# Check is = mysqli did anything, if not show error

Tags: php, mysqli

Ive got a mysqli query like so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO vacancies(title,employer,hours,pay,pay_term,location,qualification,apply,desc,status,end_date,int_start,poss_start) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param( 
    $_POST['title'], 
    $_POST['employer'],
    $_POST['hours'],
    $_POST['pay'],
    $_POST['pay_term'],
    $_POST['location'],
    $_POST['qualification'],
    $_POST['apply'],
    $_POST['desc'],
    $_POST['status'],
    $_POST['end_date'],
    $_POST['int_start'],
    $_POST['poss_start']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
}
```

and afterwards I have added:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { // exactly like this!
        echo "Yup that executed";
    }else {
        echo "There was a problem with the statement";  
    }
```

However, none of those echos work.

What I would like is a success message to be displayed if the row has entered successfully and if not display an error.

**Edit as requested**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else {
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO vacancies(title,employer,hours,pay,pay_term,location,qualification,apply,employdesc,status,end_date,int_start,poss_start) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        $stmt->bind_param( 
        $_POST['title'], 
        $_POST['employer'],
        $_POST['hours'],
        $_POST['pay'],
        $_POST['pay_term'],
        $_POST['location'],
        $_POST['qualification'],
        $_POST['apply'],
        $_POST['employdesc'],
        $_POST['status'],
        $_POST['end_date'],
        $_POST['int_start'],
        $_POST['poss_start']);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->close();


    }

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

**Edit, Schema**
[image: Schema]

Comment: well if if doesn't pass in the if nor the else, then your code is failing before that, either in the `prepare` or the `bind` statement. didi you by any chance remove error messages output ?

Comment: You need to find yourself a tutorial and learn how to use mysqli from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a MySQL [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Either choose another name or wrap it in backticks

```
(title,employer,hours,pay,pay_term,location,qualification,apply,`desc`,status,end_date,int_start,poss_start)
```

Plus,

Replace with: (not knowing what your DB schema is, modify if columns are INT)

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", 
$_POST['title'], 
$_POST['employer'],
$_POST['hours'],
$_POST['pay'],
$_POST['pay_term'],
$_POST['location'],
$_POST['qualification'],
$_POST['apply'],
$_POST['desc'],
$_POST['status'],
$_POST['end_date'],
$_POST['int_start'],
$_POST['poss_start']);

$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Add error reporting:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
```

---

### Edit - test DB

Here is my test code:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$db = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$_POST['name'] = "Larry";
$_POST['pay'] = 50.5;

$sql = "INSERT INTO my_test_table (name, pay, date) VALUES (?,?,NOW())";
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    die($db->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['pay']);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die($stmt->error);
}

else{
echo "Data entered.";
}

$stmt->close();
```